# flutter - How to stop alarm in notifcations

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, material-ui

I am using flutter local notifications and alarm package but i am not able to stop the alarm. alarm is being played but not ablt to stop the alarm.

here is my code

```
  final alarmSettings = AlarmSettings(
    id: 42,
    dateTime: DateTime.now(),
    assetAudioPath: 'assets/ringtone/alarm.mp3',
    loopAudio: true,
    vibrate: true,
    fadeDuration: 3.0,
    notificationTitle: 'This is the title',
    notificationBody: 'This is the body',
    enableNotificationOnKill: true,
    stopOnNotificationOpen: true,
  );

  Future<void> scheduleNotification() async {
    await Alarm.set(alarmSettings: alarmSettings);
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'channel_id',
      'channel_name',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
    );
    const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0, // Notification ID
      'Notification Title', // Notification Title
      'Notification Body', // Notification Body
      platformChannelSpecifics,
    );
  }
```

i want to stop the alarm if user taps on the notification or dimisses the notification.